# How to show only 2 rows after the GROUPBY in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like:

```
Company  Country
ABC      USA
ABC      USA
BCD      USA
BCD      USA
ABC      USA
```

The output should be : -

```
Company  Country
ABC      USA
BCD      USA
```

Comment: What `groupby` do you use?

Comment: Or better what is your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) if need unique values in all columns:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
print (df)
  Company Country
0     ABC     USA
2     BCD     USA
```

Or if need specify column(s) for check duplicates add parameter `subset`:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Company'])
print (df)
  Company Country
0     ABC     USA
2     BCD     USA
```

And solution with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df = df.groupby('Company', as_index=False).first()
print (df)
  Company Country
0     ABC     USA
1     BCD     USA
```

Comment: Are you sure? This has nothing to do with groupby (which OP wants apparently)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - It is a bit unclear, so I try get desired output. But I am not sure.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, OP doesn't seem to need to `groupby` - there is no aggregation, no reduction, etc.

Comment: @MaxU - Thank you.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Thank you for comments.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of completeness, you can also use:

```
df.groupby('Company').head(1)
Out: 
  Company Country
0     ABC     USA
2     BCD     USA
```